# Spring reactive security with basic authentication for rest api

Tags: spring-security-rest, spring-reactive

I'm having problems with Spring Security Reactive + basic authentication + rest api + react redux.

I'm trying to implement authentication from the react (client side). In case of correct username and password its working properly. But if case of wrong credential instead of returning 401 my request get's cancel and for a send the basic authentication pops up and goes. therefore I can't handle the wrong credential scenario.

below are the screen shot of the error.

[image]

[image]

[image]